# Loop not finishing

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, after-effects

for some reason my loop is only going through once despite `importedChar.numItems =2`

After effects item start on 1 instead of 0, so I use `x=1`, Here's what I have

```
for(x=1; x < importedChar.numItems; x++) {
    if (importedChar.item(x) instanceof CompItem) {
        //Add imported Char to Main Comp
        var newObj = null;      
        var newObj = myComp.layers.add(importedChar.item(x))

        //Move Layer under null
        newObj.moveAfter(newNull);

        //Parent to Null
        newObj.parent = newNull;
    }    
}
```

If the first item is a composition it runs fine, but leaves the loop if it's the second

Comment: x=1 is only < 2 once.  (x++ does x => 2, which is *not* < 2)

Comment: IF `x=1`, and `x++`, then x will only be less than 2 once. You probably want `x <= importedChar.numItems`

Comment: You'll have to use `x < importedChar.numItems + 1` then.

Comment: @Blender - `x <= importedChar.numItems` is much more preferable

Comment: @kinsho: It's personal preference. I find it easier to glance at the `+ 1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `<=` instead of `<` to get it to run twice.

**Edit:** Alternatively, `for(x=0; x < importedChar.numItems; x++) {` and then use `x+1` when you need to use it, but in situations where you can avoid that, `<=` is preferable.

Situations when you'd want the alternative usually arise when you need to access an index *and* a meaningful value (e.g. to print a human-friendly error message)

Answer (score 2):

`x = 1, importedChar.numItems =2, x < importedChar.numItems true;`

then `x = 2, importedChar.numItems =2, x < importedChar.numItems false;` 
so out the loop

Im guessing this way